# Do you set yourself daily goals and stop once you've reached them?

Tags: creative-writing, technique

I don't follow any kind of time or word limit. I write when I have time and stop when the time is over (e.g. time to eat, to work, to sleep).

But now I'm thinking of setting myself some daily goals to see if this improves the quality of my writing (e.g. 2000 per day, 5 hours a day), as well as my mental health and sanity.

Do you set yourself daily goals? Do you stop once you've reached them? What are the pro and cons you've noticed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to the first! Emphatic no to the second. If I'm on a roll, I'll keep writing until I run out of words. In order to start writing, I have to make a plan and stick to it, otherwise I'll get distracted and forget. I also have to purge my mind of the idea of "writing mood" because if I wait until I'm in the mood, I end up writing nothing.

Setting aside time to write is a good disciplinary practice. Setting word goals is also helpful, if only so that you can fail to reach them. Failure allows you to better gauge how much you can really write in a set time period. Last month I made myself a spreadsheet to track my daily words, but life interfered and I got very little done. This month I am more optimistic.

Even though concrete goals have a lot of advantages, not everyone can work with them, just as not everyone can work from an outline, and not everyone can write a snappy, plot-driven story. It's hard work to find the routine that works for you, but it's incredibly rewarding once you start reaping the results.

Answer (score 0):

Setting goals can be good. Especially if it helps motivate you.

But stopping when you've reached your goals is a classic mistake which is described in every game theory or economics book. This is best illustrated with taxi drivers. Taxi drivers tend to set themselves a daily number of passengers to transport. As a result, there are more taxi drivers working on days when the demand for taxi drivers is low, and fewer taxi drivers working on days when the demand for taxi drivers is high.

This goes for writing too. There are good days when you're productive, have good ideas, and take pleasure in writing; and bad days when you don't. If you set yourself a daily limit and stop when you reach it, then you'll be working long hours on the bad days and short hours on the good days, which is the exact opposite of what you want.

In other words:

- If you're on a roll, then keep going! Make the most of that roll. Don't interrupt it just because you've reached your daily quota.
- If you've already spent a long time writing today but still haven't met your daily quota, because you've been less productive than usual, or have enjoyed writing less than usual, then don't punish yourself by making this bad day last longer just to reach your daily quota.

Answer (score 0):

So when I'm in writing mode, I set a goal of about 1500 words a day, broken into three sessions of 30-45 minutes with a goal of 500 words per session.  The goal is fluid, since I will write to scene completion, not actual word count, so if the scene takes me more than 500 words, I'll write more and less if it takes less, than less.  Typically, I'll write around breakfast, lunch, and dinner.